# Лексико-семантические поля и группы слова "сутки"

Tags: лексика, семантика

интересуют лексико-семантические поля (также группы) слова "сутки"

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите  здесь, возможно, поможет:

http://cyberleninka.ru/article/n/struktura-obem-i-soderzhanie-leksiko-semanticheskogo-polya-sutki-v-soderzhanii-obucheniya-russkomu-yazyku-inostrannyh-uchaschihsya